# WSO2: Avoid hard-coding URI ports in Address Endpoint

Tags: wso2

I have configured an offset of '10' to my ESB server on the carbon.xml file. Now all deployed API's are pointing to the port 8290.

In my API I am calling another API via an Http Endpoint. I am setting the URI template manually to: http://localhost:8290/paramAPI, as follows:

```
<send>
   <endpoint>
      <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/paramAPI"/>
   </endpoint>
</send>
```

However I also want to deploy to other server instances. For example, I would like to deploy to a server with an offset of '20', and therefore the '/paramAPI' would no longer be reachable at port '8290', instead on '8300'.

In this case, the Http endpoint inside the send mediator must become:

```
<send>
   <endpoint>
      <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8300/paramAPI"/>
   </endpoint>
</send>
```

I am searching for a method to parameterize the port value.

I have tried to use local entries by defining a string variable on the server by the name APIPort. When referencing it, I modified the HTTP endpoint as follows:

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
       <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:{APIPort}/paramAPI"/>
    </endpoint>
 </send>
```

but I got: java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "{APIPort}"

What is the best approach to parameterize URI's? if local entries are used then what is the proper way to use them as parameters and reference them in the URI?

Much appreciated and kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

if I recall correctly you should use `uri.var` for your uri-template properties. Try to name your property `uri.var.APIPort` instead.

To be sure I created a simple API , see the following example:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testapi" context="/test" version="1" version-type="context">
   <resource methods="POST GET">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="uri.var.version" value="v2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://mocky.io/{uri.var.version}/5d1dec2a3000006a00d7239d"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Hello Jan, and thanks for the response. After using the variable in this format, I am calling the api from an address mediator: http://localhost:{uri.var.APIPort}/paramAPI, still with the same error implying malformed URI

Comment: Hi Moe, note, this only works in an API. Not in a proxy service. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Any luck fixing your problem?

Comment: Hi Jan, and thanks for asking. Actually I am still trying to find a solution, but I am going for another approach. So far it seems that it's impossible to 'parameterize' the port, so instead I am saving the address in a local entry with the value 'http://localhost:8280' (for example), and in the API I will be constructing the call using a Header mediator and a default endpoint mediator.

Comment: Ah, also a good solution. Another might be to use maven profiles. (add a profile called 'production' set the production parameters like 'httpport'there and use {$httpport} to reference them in the project) There is a blog here, only something seems to have gone wrong with escaping: https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-how-to-change-proxy-parameters-at-build-time

Comment: Thank you Jan for the link, it is very interesting and I will look into implementing it. However it seems that to implement this method means that I will no longer be able to directly deploy from the Developer Studio to the WSO2 server, as per the last note in the article.

Comment: Ah yes, that is a disadvantage. I think there might be a workaround around this as there is also a maven deploy plugin, but it is quite tricky to configure: https://www.yenlo.com/blog/eight-ways-to-deploy-a-car-file-to-wso2